# How to calculate number of days since new version is available on App Store iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, version

In my project, App is already available on App Store. Whenever new version is available on App Store, App should prompt popup that says new version is available and link to update it. User can Update it now or later by clicking on respective buttons.

I am able to achieve this by fetching information about app from App Store against Bundled Identifier.

```
NSURL *lookupURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", bundleIdentifier]];
NSData *lookupResults = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:lookupURL];
NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:lookupResults options:0 error:nil];
```

Then trough received JSON, I can get Information about new available version number, supported devices and so on.

```
jsonResults ---> {
    resultCount = 1;
    results =     (
                {
            advisories =             (
                "Unrestricted Web Access"
            );
            artistId = @@@@@@@@@;
            artistName = @@@@@@@@@;
            artistViewUrl = @@@@@@@@@";
            artworkUrl100 = @@@@@@@@@";
            artworkUrl512 = @@@@@@@@@;
            artworkUrl60 = @@@@@@@@@;
            bundleId = @@@@@@@@@;
            contentAdvisoryRating = @@@@@@@@@;
            currency = USD;
            description = @@@@@@@@@;
            features =             (
                iosUniversal
            );
            fileSizeBytes = @@@@@@@@@;
            formattedPrice = Free;
            genreIds =             (
                @@@@@@@@@
            );
            genres =             (
                @@@@@@@@@
            );
            ipadScreenshotUrls =             (
                @@@@@@@@@
            );
            isGameCenterEnabled = 0;
            isVppDeviceBasedLicensingEnabled = 1;
            kind = software;
            languageCodesISO2A =             (
                @@@@@@@@@@@
            );
            minimumOsVersion = "7.0";
            price = 0;
            primaryGenreId = @@@@@@@@@;
            primaryGenreName = @@@@@@@@@;
            releaseDate = "2014-07-13@@@@@@@";
            releaseNotes = @@@@@@@@@;
            screenshotUrls =             (
                @@@@@@@@@
            );
            sellerName = @@@@@@@@@;
            supportedDevices =             (
                @@@@@@@@@@@
            );
            trackCensoredName = @@@@@@@@@;
            trackContentRating = "17+";
            trackId = @@@@@@@@@;
            trackName = @@@@@@@@@;
            trackViewUrl = @@@@@@@@@;
            version = "2.0";
            wrapperType = software;
        }
    );
}
```

Now I want to calculate since how many days new version was available and user has not updated it. JSON that I received does not contain Latest Updated Version Date.

Is there any way to know this time gap directly form App Store.

Comment: can you just post the sample reponse whcj you currently storing in jsonResults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am unable to get latest App version's release date from Apple's received JSON, I am doing it by keeping new version's release date on server side.

For that every time I submit new App update to Apple, I have to manually check whether new App version is available on App Store or not. Then I set that version's release date on server side.

In my App, whenever App is launch I call web service which returns me new App Version and its release date.

Comment: Please write more specific to the question of the questioner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is the "releaseDate" value.. Make an NSDate object and a date formatter, set it up and parse the substring of that value and you have a date object. Then compare the two dates. [NSDate date] gives you today.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can see that 'releaseDate' key in JSON (as I posted that JSON by myself), and I think you haven't read my question or description properly. I don't want date at which App got first time release on AppStore that I can get from 'releaseDate' , I want date of last Update of App was available on AppStore. As updates can be 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3 so on, I want last update's date.